# In Scala cats-laws, why is the functor composition law different from canonical definition?

Tags: scala, functor, scala-cats, category-theory

The (covariant) functor definition in cats-laws looks like this:

```
  def covariantComposition[A, B, C](fa: F[A], f: A => B, g: B => C): IsEq[F[C]] =
    fa.map(f).map(g) <-> fa.map(f.andThen(g))
```

But if I translate the functor composition rule to Scala, it should be:

[image: rule]

```
  def covariantComposition[A, B, C](fa: F[A], f: A => B, g: B => C): IsEq[F[C]] =
    fa.map(f).andThen(fa.map(g)) <-> fa.map(f.andThen(g))
```

Why are they different? Which version is correct?

**UPDATE 1** I'm aware of a similar implementation in Haskell, but I haven't had a chance to read it. I wonder if the Haskell version is more by the book.

Comment: What is this `fa.map(f).andThen` even supposed to mean ? `andThen` is defined on `Functions` for functional composition... `fa.map(f)` gives you `F[B]`... now how is `andThen` even supposed to work with this `Functor` ? Also where is the reference for your given definition of functor composition ?

Comment: @sarveshseri It's just on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor

Comment: the output of the functor `F[_]` applied are `F[A] => F[B]` and `F[B] => F[C]` respectively, looks all good to me: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tribbloid/VyyLFjLwQDiwB8Gs6mYbkA/10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`F(g ∘ f) = F(g) ∘ F(f)` is the same as `∀fa, (F(g ∘ f))(fa) = (F(g) ∘ F(f))(fa)` (equality of functions is equality of images for all arguments, this is *extensionality* in HoTT [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403122/when-do-two-functions-become-equal) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346220/uniqueness-principle-for-functions-types-in-the-hott-book) [3](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/function+extensionality)).

The latter is translated as

```
def covariantComposition[A, B, C](fa: F[A], f: A => B, g: B => C): IsEq[F[C]] =
  fa.map(f).map(g) <-> fa.map(f.andThen(g))
```

(actually, `fa.map(f.andThen(g)) <-> fa.map(f).map(g)`).

If you'd like to have "point-free" `F(g ∘ f) = F(g) ∘ F(f)` you could write `_.map(f.andThen(g)) <-> _.map(f).map(g)` or `_.map(f.andThen(g)) <-> (_.map(f)).andThen(_.map(g))` (this is `fmap (g . f) = fmap g . fmap f` in Haskell, or more precisely, in some "meta-Haskell").

The 2nd code snippet in your question

```
def covariantComposition[A, B, C](fa: F[A], f: A => B, g: B => C): IsEq[F[C]] =
  fa.map(f).andThen(fa.map(g)) <-> fa.map(f.andThen(g))
```

is incorrect. `fa.map(f).andThen...` doesn't make sense as it was mentioned in comments. You seem to confuse `F` and `F[A]`.

In category theory, in general categories, `f: A -> B` can be just arrows, not necessarily functions (e.g. related pairs in a [pre-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) if a category is this pre-order), so `(F(g ∘ f))(fa)` can make no sense. But the category of types in Scala (or Haskell) is a category where objects are types and morphisms are functions.

Comment: Sorry I just realised that I read it incorrectly, the `.map` used in the law belongs to `Functor.Ops`, it is the inside-out and curried version of `Functor.map`. So in the end this question shouldn't exist :)

Answer (score 3):

I think your confusion comes from the different way functor map property can be represented.

```scala
trait Functor[F[_]] {
 
  def map1[A, B](f: A => B): F[A] => F[B]

  def map2[A, B](f: A => B)(fa: F[A]): F[B]

  def map3[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]

}
```

Here... `map1` is the haskell aligned definition... and hence the functor law representation used by haskell also works with this one.

So, this haskell

```hs
fmap (g . f) = fmap g . fmap f
```

translates to following Scala

```scala
map1( g.compose(f) ) = map1(g).compose( map1(f) )

// or 
map1( f.andThen(g) ) <-> map1(f).andThen(map1(g))
```

But, the thing is that we have few more ways to represent the same `map` property as given by `map2` and `map3`. The overall essens is still the same, we just switched the representation.

Now, when we add the full object oriented angle to it... the "object-oriented" `Functor` becomes something like following.

```scala
trait List[+A] {
  def map(f: A => B): List[B]
}
```

So... for the "object oriented functor" like `List`, the same law can be represented as following

```
listA.map(f).map(g) <-> listA.map(f.andThen(g))
```

And, you are seeing exactly this.

Comment: I see, that make sense. Good to know that Haskell is using the more by the book definition

Comment: I don't know if cats made a good decision tho, there are some type information loss on F[B] comparing to F[A => B], which may cause some problems in summoning type classes precisely

Comment: @tribbloid Actually, `fmap (g . f) = fmap g . fmap f` is not Haskell. It some meta-Haskell. Equality is not defined for functions in Haskell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906628/equality-of-functions-in-haskell

Comment: @tribbloid I guess you still have some confusion. There doesn't seem to be a type information loss. And type-class laws `... <-> ...` don't make impact on *summoning* type classes in Scala.

Comment: In cats this law is enforced by an elaborated property-based test framework, summoning is not required. It may be necessary for a less leaky, more symbolic enforcement, which I don't know yet. In the future I may need to write an autodiff example using this method, just to see which definition is more capable